# Error handling with Typescript and Express in Node.js

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm starting with Node and Typescript and I have a question.

I have these 2 files.

server.ts

```
import express = require('express');
import IConfiguration from "../config/config";


export default class Server {

    public app: express.Application;
    public configuration: IConfiguration;

    constructor( configuration: IConfiguration ) {
        this.configuration = configuration;
        this.app = express();
    }

    static init(configuration: IConfiguration) {
        return new Server(configuration);
    }

    start(callback: Function) {
        this.app.listen(this.configuration.port, callback());
        this.app.use(express.static(this.configuration.public_path))
    }
}
```

index.ts

```
import Server from './server/server';
import Configuration from "./config/config";
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import router from './router/router';

//Loading .env file
dotenv.config();

//Init config
const configuration = Configuration.init();

//Init server
const server = Server.init(configuration);
server.app.use(router);
server.start(() => {
   console.log('Server running at port ' + configuration.port);
});
```

In index.ts I have the app.listen callback on start function, but I dont know how write this error handling for capture the errors.
How I can add this .on("error") on my callback function?

```
server.start(() => {
   console.log('Listening on port: ', port);
}).on('error', (e) => {
   console.log('Error happened: ', e.message)
});
```

I have tried put this in my index.ts but I get this error: 
"Property 'on' does not exist on type 'void'"

Answer (score 0):

Your `server` variable is an instance of your `Server` class and when you call `start` it does not return anything, it just implicitly returns `undefined` (or `void` in Typescript terms) and `undefined` surely does not have `on` method, so you cannot chain it like that. This is what error message says, basically.

What you can do is return `this.app` from `start` method, for example.

```
    start(callback: Function) {
        this.app.listen(this.configuration.port, callback());
        this.app.use(express.static(this.configuration.public_path))
        return this.app;
    }
```

Or separate this two line like this:

```
server.start(() => {
   console.log('Listening on port: ', port);
});

server.app.on('error', (e) => {
   console.log('Error happened: ', e.message)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot pass "err" to app.listen in express. I think you guys are confusing with http server:

const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);

```
server.on('error', (err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
 
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log('Running')
});
```